# how to solve warning Use callback in setState when referencing the previous state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, eslint, lint

For this piece of code, I am getting eslint warning: warning  Use callback in setState when referencing the previous state  react/no-access-state-in-setstate

how can it be solved?

```js
const sketch = await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(this.state.sketch, [{ rotate: 90 }], {
  base64: true,
  format: ImageManipulator.SaveFormat.PNG,
})
this.setState({ sketch: sketch.uri })
```

It is showing a warning for first-line(`const sketch =....`).

Comment: Use functional state update. What's the initial value of `this.state.sketch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting warning because of `this.setState({ sketch: sketch.uri })` line.

You can do something like the below code to remove the lint warning.

```js
const sketch = await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(this.state.sketch, [{ rotate: 90 }], {
  base64: true,
  format: ImageManipulator.SaveFormat.PNG,
})
this.setState(() => {
  return {
    sketch: sketch.uri,
  }
})
```